# how counting down the days in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and I have not worked with NSDate. For my app I need how to make to calculate how many days there are until the event. The date of the event is written with DatePicker on Firebase, and I need to calculate from the current date how many days are left until the day it's written. All I need is to count down the days.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data from DatePicker to `Date` object, and you can use the following function which returns an `Int`, a representation of the number of days to a passed date.

```
func daysTo(date: Date) -> Int? {
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
    return components.day
}
```

Comment: My picker view is in another view Controller... can you help me how to pass data?

Comment: Please see: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension for find difference between date:

```
extension Date {
    
    public func diffrenceTime() -> (Int, Int) {
        var cal = Calendar.init(identifier: .persian)
        let d1 = Date()
        let components = cal.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: self, to: d1)
        let diffHour = components.hour!
        let diffMinute = components.minute!
        
        return (diffHour, diffMinute)
    }
    
    public func fullDistance(from date: Date, resultIn component: Calendar.Component, calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int? {
        calendar.dateComponents([component], from: self, to: date).value(for: component)
    }

    public func distance(from date: Date, only component: Calendar.Component, calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        let days1 = calendar.component(component, from: self)
        let days2 = calendar.component(component, from: date)
        return days1 - days2
    }

    public func hasSame(_ component: Calendar.Component, as date: Date) -> Bool {
        self.distance(from: date, only: component) == 0
    }
}
```

example for use:

```
let dateOne = Date() // or any date
            let dateTwo = getDateFromServer // your second date for
            
            // option One
            let distanceDay = dateOne.fullDistance(from: dateTwo, resultIn: .day)
            
            var cal = Calendar.current // for your calendar
            cal.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "EN")
            // option Two
            let distanceDay = dateOne.fullDistance(from: dateTwo, resultIn: .day, calendar: cal)
```

you can set hour, minute or any Component for find difference instead of day in result parameter